# SignalR Connection fails in Iphone safari browser gets minimized. How to make it stay connected ? or How to Reconnect when Tab gets active

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using Signal-R Core, a simple chat page. I logged in with different clients like browser in laptop, mobile browser both Android and IOS,

I could able to send message to all clients, But when mobile browser(only IOS) gets minimized Signal-R connection disconnected,

I've tried implementing a logic to reconnect. Idea is to set a flag on connection.close() get called, And then starting the connection by calling connection.start() on Window.focus() get called. Window.focus() function is working properly.

This works as 1 after 1 time the browser minimized, Only on iPhone browser.
Scenario : Initially connected, message sent successfully.
Now browser minimized, and then opened again and sending message from iPhone client, now gets failed.
Then again minimized and opened again the browser, sending from iPhone client, now message sent successfully.

Tried it multiple times. works same.

```
var flagConnection = true;

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();
connection.on("BroadcastMessage", function ( user, message) {
    var encodedMsg =  user + ": " + message;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    $("#divChatMessages").append(li);
});

connection.start();

connection.onclose(function(change) {

    if(connection.connectionState == 0)
        flagConnection = false;
    else
        flagConnection = true;
});


window.addEventListener("focus", function(event) 
    { 
        if(flagConnection == false){
            connection.start();
            flagConnection = true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried to set an onload and/or a ready event to check if the connection is alive cause safari has a strange event firing mechanism i had the same issues once and i solved with an event wich gets always called in the browser when you leave and return.

Comment: @AlexCr onLoad or ready function will get triggered on page first time load. my case is not even reloading the page.

Comment: i know but there are some events wich get refired when the site goes in foreground and it's not the onfocus event cause why would it be logical it's apple.

Comment: could you please state that functions @AlexCr or share me the link to docs.

Comment: With this implementation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API